# REACT ROUTER - Class component (only) - rendering page - JSON File

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

i'm working on react router project (im beginner) to improve my skillz.

**my problem:**

I have a JSON file (Dragon ball Z). When i click on characters (like goku) i want to show his biography.
Actually when i click on goku every biography of each characters are showed.

I know how to do it with function component (useLocation ect..) but i'm totally stuck wicth class component because i can't use hooks in it, what is the good way to do it ?

here is the project :
[DBZ REACT ROUTES](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uqbvn3?file=src/API.js)

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `react-router-dom` v6 we can use `useParams` to read the params key within function component.
With `class component` you can write an **HOC** function to archive the same thing

> a higher-order component is a function that takes a component and returns a new component

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function withParams(Component) {
  return props => <Component {...props} params={useParams()} />;
}

class Charbio extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let { id } = this.props.params;
    // get the bio by id here
  }

  render() {
    return API.map((element) => {
      return <p>{element.bio}</p>;
    });
  }
}

export default withParams(Charbio);
```